# Determine via C++ whether a program is installed in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, repository, system, package-managers

I would like to make a `system` call to a Linux program from my C++ code, but I would like to check whether the program is installed on the user's machine first.

In Ubuntu, I can determine whether a package associated with that program was installed using a system call like `dpkg -s gifsicle` and parse its output. [`gifsicle`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gifsicle) here is the program name.

However, it's possible that the program (e.g. `gifsicle`) was compiled from source and thus does not appear in the Ubuntu package repository.

What's a good programmatic way of determining whether a program (e.g. `gifsicle`) is available on the system executing the C++ code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard package manager for Linux, so `dpkg` is definitely the wrong answer.

For security and correctness reasons, it is probably unwise to rely on the user's PATH to locate an executable.  So you probably should already be using the fully-qualified path (e.g. `/usr/bin/gifsicle`) in your call to `system`.

If so, the easy answer to your question is:

```
if (access("/usr/bin/gifsicle", X_OK) == 0) {
    system("/usr/bin/gifsicle -my -args");
}
else if (errno == EACCESS) {
    /* gifsicle not found */
}
else {
    /* access() failed!  Operating system is broken or Windows (or both) */
}
```

(Bonus points if you put `/usr/bin/gifsicle` into a variable)

The harder -- but arguably "more correct" -- answer is to avoid `system` and do `fork` + `execl` yourself, checking the `execl` to see if it results in `ENOENT` or similar.  Communicating the failure back to the parent process could be annoying, though.

Answer (score 4):

You could invoke [`which`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which) first.

The exit status indicates whether it could find the specified executable on the path.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to cover the case where the program is installed manually and is not registered in the installed packages database, you would have to scan the entire file system to guarantee that the program is not installed.

If you are sure the program is in the user's PATH, you can invoke the `which` command (also using `system()`).

However, the common solution to this is to allow the user to override the path to the executable via a configuration option.  For example, [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) may be configured to invoke [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/%C2%B8) to generate diagrams.  By default, it tries to invoke `dot` as it it were on the PATH environment variable.  If it cannot be found, it warns the user that it cannot find the `dot` program and that the [`DOT_PATH`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_dot_path) configuration value has not been set.  This solution has the advantage of being simple *and* working on other systems too.

Comment: Minor nitpick: "repository" usually means the collection of all packages available on the net, not the ones installed locally.

Comment: @Tomalak: used "installed packages database" instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it's not trivial to determine whether something is installed. Really, there is no clear definition of "installed"; package managers get close, but not everything goes through a package manager.

Why not just attempt to invoke the executable? If the call fails, and `system` indicates that the executable was not found, then just presume that it's not installed and/or not available — does it matter which? — and move on to some fallback alternative.

Answer (score -3):

sounds like you are trying to make a configure script (or similar)

see autoconf

http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/autoconf/html_chapter/autoconf_3.html

Comment: Not really. He's not trying to do conditional builds. He wants a runtime check of the environment.