# cmake - How to make sure a program(dependency) is installed on users machine

Tags: c, linux, cmake, dependencies

My c programm(for linux) needs users to have a specific programm lets say "foo" be installed to work. I am using cmake to generate build files.

This program is to be distributed.

How can I make sure that it is installed using cmake.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299708/detecting-if-program-is-installed-on-machine) but it's for checking at runtime. I want to check it before building the program.

Comment: I think you'll need to you a package manager that checks for require dependencies before running the cmake utility, if not mistaken (depending on Linux flavor) apt, https://devconnected.com/apt-package-manager-on-linux-explained/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `foo` provides a CMake package, use [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) to find `foo`:

```
find_package(foo REQUIRED)

# Use the foo::foo imported target or foo_EXECUTABLE cache variable
```

There are [many built-in packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html#find-modules) for CMake including `Python` and `FLEX`.

---

If `foo` does *not* provide a CMake package and you only need the path to the executable, then you can use [`find_program`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html):

```
find_program(Foo_EXECUTABLE foo REQUIRED)
```

From here you can use the `Foo_EXECUTABLE` variable in your `execute_process` or `add_custom_command` calls.